# how to better scale this image? (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I might be going about this the wrong way. I have two columns, and the right one is an image. I set a padding on `.back`, and I want the image I created to both

1. be responsive. IE, resize proportionally so that parts of it are never cut off. I believe this is achieved right now already.
2. use all the space given to it. I don't understand why this image's right edge ends before the right side of the page. I've set width to 100%, using `container-fluid`, and the columns add up to 12. Thoughts?

As a second question, i've added `text-center` to the div around the image so why is the image not centered when the window size is very small?

```css
.fluid-img {
width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.back {
 padding-top: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = 'back'>
<div class = 'container-fluid'> 
<div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <h2 class="title"> Title</h2>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--//col-->

            <div class='col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/g4sTWMZ.png" class = 'fluid-img'>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
                  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the code.. the image you are using has huge blank space at the right side as it's a png image you cannot see it.. download the image and crop it.. your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

1. To better Scale your Image you should use img-responsive calss of bootstrap.
2. Your image ends before the right edge because it contains transparent pixels     at the right side, I cropped your image and now it looks fine.
3. Your image was not getting centered because of the transparent pixels at the right side.

```css
.fluid-img {
width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.back {
 padding-top: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = 'back'>
<div class = 'container-fluid'> 
<div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <h2 class="title"> Title</h2>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--//col-->

            <div class='col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/FFeYNDn.png" class= 'fluid-img img img-responsive'>

                </div>
            </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```